# Suppose f(n) = O(h(n)) and g(n) = O(h(n)). Is f(n) * g(n) = O(h(n) * h(n))?

Tags: asymptotics, proof-techniques

I understand this should be a relatively easy proof, but I can't seem to understand how to do it.

I know that, by Big O definition:

- there exists some value $c_1$ where $f(n) \le c_1 \cdot h(n)$ for all $n \ge n_0'$
- there exists some value $c_2$ where $g(n) \le c_2 \cdot h(n)$ for all $n >= n_0''$

and I have to find some value $c$ and $n_0$ where

$f(n) \cdot g(n) \le c \cdot h(n) \cdot h(n)$ for all $n \ge n_0$

How would I search for those values $c$ and $N_0$? What would the first steps be?

Comment: Hint: try $C = C_1 C_2$.

Comment: Second half of hint: consider maximum of $N0'$ and $N0''$.

Comment: Third half of hint: if $a \leq c$ and $b\leq c$, then $ab \leq c^2$.